# SASS: Returning set of different CSS properties from a mixin or function

Tags: html, css, function, sass, mixins

I've few DIVs in my template which **have common properties but different values for each property**. These are listed below

- letter-spacing
- text-transform
- font-family
- font-weight
- font-size
- color

Mixins accept only params based on the property, and function returns a single value.

I want to know if SASS/SCSS has any utility to handle the same. I should pass the values as arguments to SASS and it should return all the CSS properties updated with the arguments.

Comment: Take a look at the if / else functions in SASS: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a logic for this problem using **mixins**.

I have created a Mixin that accepts all the **params passed as a list, hence declaration ends in ...**
This solution also **covers optional CSS properties** which may not be included in all the classes but majority of them.

### styles.scss

```
.blog-content {
    // for .destination
    @include text-properties("destination", "EpicRide", normal, 65px, $standard-black, none, 2.8px, '', '');
    // for .intro-title
    @include text-properties("intro-title", "Montserrat", 500, 14px, $standard-black, uppercase, 2.8px, 5px 5% 0, '');
    // for .place
    @include text-properties("place", "Montserrat", 500, 14px, $standard-black, uppercase, 2.8px, inherit, '');
    // for .description
    @include text-properties("description", "Lora", 400, 16px, $standard-light, none, 0, 0 5%, 20px);
}
```

### _variables.scss

```
@mixin text-properties($args... ) {  // args has a list of arguments
    $class: nth($args, 1);  // nth is used to extract 'nth' argument's value
    $font-family: nth($args, 2);
    $font-weight: nth($args, 3);
    $font-size: nth($args, 4);
    $color: nth($args, 5);
    $text-transform: nth($args, 6);
    $letter-spacing: nth($args, 7);
    $padding: nth($args, 8);
    $margin-top: nth($args, 9);

    .#{$class} {  // create class dynamically. Mention the variable name inside #{} to fetch it's value
        font-family: $font-family;
        font-weight: $font-weight;
        font-size: $font-size;
        color: $color;
        text-transform: $text-transform;
        letter-spacing: $letter-spacing;
        @if $padding != '' {  // condition to ensure property is added only if valid param is passed.
            padding: $padding;
        }
        @if $margin-top != '' {
            margin-top: $margin-top;
        }
    }
}
```

### Resultant CSS

```
.blog-content .destination {
  font-family: "EpicRide";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 65px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: 2.8px;
}
.blog-content .intro-title {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2.8px;
  padding: 5px 5% 0;
}
.blog-content .place {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2.8px;
  padding: inherit;
}
.blog-content .description {
  font-family: "Lora";
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: rgb(var(--LightColorRGB));
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  padding: 0 5%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

This solution has one limitation though, an increase in the number of CSS properties would increase the mixin code.

I hope this will solve your issue. Suggestions/Comments are welcomed to improve this logic.